# Downloading 3rd party source code for python

Tags: python, dependencies

I have a python script with several 3rd party dependencies. I want to be able to write a script that pulls down the source code for these dependencies locally, and then zips everything up so I can send it to another service to use. Is any alternate ways to do this besides writing several lines that download the codes using the url that they point to?

Comment: Do you mean like https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-from-local-packages?

Comment: Do you want to use the packages or do you really need the source? If you want to just use them you can simply write a `setup.py` and then create a built distribution in order to transfer them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the requirements.txt method does exactly what I want, but is there a way to do it without that? So that if dependencies are added or removed the reuirements.txt doesn't also have to be updated?

Comment: If your dependencies change you *want* to update the requirements file, so you have a record of what they currently are.